# Validation for Table in mySQL if all fields are set

Tags: mysql, sql, testing

we are using mySQL to create Configurations for a Product. To keep it simple. Every Product has settings like a name etc.

For Example Configuration

| product_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | tv |
| 1 | price | 3.99 |

Sometimess a Product gets a new Value like discount and we are adding the the new Value to each Product with ID, so that Configuration looks like

| product_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | tv |
| 1 | price | 3.99 |
| 1 | discount | 5% |

In our case, Product 1 can be places more as once in the config. Is there a good way to make/write a Test to insure, that every Product has the new value, we added for example with alter ****

At the end i have a lot a products in configurations and I want to write a test to ensure, that the new value is added to everyone.

Comment: What results do you want?  That is not clear.

Comment: you would alter the table you would add a new row for each

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return products that are missing keys, then one method uses aggregation to compare the keys for the product to all keys in the data:

```
select p.*
from (select product_id, group_concat(key order by key) as all_keys
      from t
      group by product_id
     ) p cross join
     (select group_concat(distinct key order by key) as all_keys
      from t
     ) master
where master.all_keys = p.all_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

When you know that the new number should  3 for each product

```
SELECT product_id FROM configuration GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```

This would give you all product_ids which have less than the 3 attributes